# Randomised solar system simulation collision detection issue

Tags: c, opengl, collision-detection, orbital-mechanics

So I've developed a fairly stable simulation of a solar system with randomised planets, using basic equations of motion and Newtonian mechanics and using OpenGL with C.

I also have some collision detection for when planets collide with each other or the sun.

My problem is, with my current code collisions are detected and planets are removed accordingly, however, when viewing the simulation planets can overlap/collide by about half of their radius (just a guess based on what I can see) before the collision is 'detected'.

I'm reasonably sure my method of collision detection is sufficient but please do correct me if I'm wrong.

The only other issue I can think of is that there is some difference between the 'units' for world coordinates, eye coordinates and so on.

Thanks very much for any and all help and/or suggestions.

Code:

```
float* vecSub( float *pV0, float *pV1, float *pVRes )
{
    if (pV0 && pV1 && pVRes)
    {
        pVRes[0] = pV0[0] - pV1[0];
        pVRes[1] = pV0[1] - pV1[1];
        pVRes[2] = pV0[2] - pV1[2];
        return pVRes;
    }
    return 0;
}

float vecLength( float *pV )
{
    if(pV) return sqrtf(pV[0]*pV[0]+pV[1]*pV[1]+pV[2]*pV[2]);
    return 0.0f;
}

float vecDistance( float *pV1, float *pV2 )
{
    float fLen=0.0f;

    if(pV1 && pV2)
    {
        float av[4];

        vecSub(pV2, pV1, av);
        fLen=vecLength(av);
    }

    return fLen;
}

if (vecDistance(pPlanet->afPosition, pPlanet1->afPosition) <= pPlanet->fRadius + pPlanet1->fRadius)
{
    //Collision resolution code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you use a small structure to describe coordinates, and another for axis-aligned bounding boxes:

```
typedef struct {
    double  x;
    double  y;
    double  z;
} vec3d;

typedef struct {
    vec3d   min;
    vec3d   max;
} box3d; /* Axis-aligned bounding box */
```

Let's say you simulate `N` spherical objects, with radii described in `double radius[]`, current coordinates in `vec3d curr[]` (or `vec3d *curr`), and previous coordinates in `vec3d prev[]` (or `vec3d *prev`).

We want to check if any objects collide or intersect, but do so efficiently.
To avoid doing unnecessary work, use an array for the axis-aligned bounding boxes, so that the box contains the spherical object at previous and current coordinates. Two objects can then only collide or intersect, if their axis-aligned bounding boxes intersect:

```
static inline double dmin(const double d1, const double d2)
{
    return (d1 <= d2) ? d1 : d2;
}

static inline double dmax(const double d1, const double d2)
{
    return (d1 >= d2) ? d1 : d2;
}

void update_boxes(box3d *box, const size_t count,
                  const vec3d *curr, const vec3d *prev,
                  const double *radius)
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        box[i].min.x = dmin(curr[i].x, prev[i].x) - radius[i];
        box[i].max.x = dmax(curr[i].x, prev[i].x) + radius[i];
        box[i].min.y = dmin(curr[i].y, prev[i].y) - radius[i];
        box[i].max.y = dmax(curr[i].y, prev[i].y) + radius[i];
        box[i].min.z = dmin(curr[i].z, prev[i].z) - radius[i];
        box[i].max.z = dmax(curr[i].z, prev[i].z) + radius[i];
    }
}
```

To calculate the boxes, we take the center coordinates, and expand the box by the radius. (The axis-aligned bounding boxes do not need to be exact; they only need to cover the spheres at both positions. If they are larger, it just means we'll do some unnecessary work. We use axis-aligned bounding boxes, because checking if two of them intersect is extremely fast.)

If we assume the two spherical objects have constant velocity during each time step, then the position at time `t` (`0 <= t && t <= 1`) during the time step are

```
xi(t) = (1-t)*prev[i].x + t*curr[i].x;
yi(t) = (1-t)*prev[i].y + t*curr[i].y;
zi(t) = (1-t)*prev[i].z + t*curr[i].z;
```

This is simple [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) in 3D between the two positions. `t = 0` at previous time step, `t = 1` at current time step.

If we form an equation of the squared distance between two such objects, at indexes `i` and `k`, we get

```
L(t) = SQUARE( ((1-t)*prev[i].x + t*curr[i].x) - ((1-t)*prev[k].x + t*prev[k].x) )
     + SQUARE( ((1-t)*prev[i].y + t*curr[i].y) - ((1-t)*prev[k].y + t*prev[k].y) )
     + SQUARE( ((1-t)*prev[i].z + t*curr[i].z) - ((1-t)*prev[k].z + t*prev[k].z) )
```

where `SQUARE(expr) = (expr)*(expr)`. It reaches a minimum when its derivative is zero. If we solve that for `t`, we find that there is exactly one real root, meaning the two objects along those linear paths at constant velocities, come closest to each other at time `t`:

```
t = ( (prev[i].x - prev[k].x) * ( (prev[i].x - prev[j].x) - (curr[i].x - curr[k].x) )
    + (prev[i].y - prev[k].y) * ( (prev[i].y - prev[j].y) - (curr[i].y - curr[k].y) )
    + (prev[i].z - prev[k].z) * ( (prev[i].z - prev[j].z) - (curr[i].z - curr[k].z) )
    ) / ( SQUARE( (prev[i].x - prev[k].x) - (curr[i].x - curr[k].x) )
        + SQUARE( (prev[i].y - prev[k].y) - (curr[i].y - curr[k].y) )
        + SQUARE( (prev[i].z - prev[k].z) - (curr[i].z - curr[k].z) ) )
```

This is only valid if the divisor is nonzero (it can never be negative, because it is a sum of squares).

We are only interested the cases where `t >= 0` and `t <= 1`; that is, the cases where the two objects came closest to each other between the previous and current time steps.

If that does occur, all we need to do is plug `t` back in to the equation, and compare to `SQUARE(radius[i] + radius[k])` to find out if the two objects collided.

Let's look at an example function that also calculates the axis-aligned bounding boxes, uses those for fast selection, and should detect the collisions properly:

```
void handle_collisions(const size_t        count,
                       box3d       *const  box,
                       vec3d       *const  curr,
                       const vec3d *const  prev,
                       const double *const radius)
{
    size_t  i, k;

    for (k = 0; k < count; k++) {
        box[k].min.x = dmin(prev[k].x, curr[k].x) - radius[k];
        box[k].max.x = dmax(prev[k].x, curr[k].x) + radius[k];
        box[k].min.y = dmin(prev[k].y, curr[k].y) - radius[k];
        box[k].max.y = dmax(prev[k].y, curr[k].y) + radius[k];
        box[k].min.z = dmin(prev[k].z, curr[k].z) - radius[k];
        box[k].max.z = dmax(prev[k].z, curr[k].z) + radius[k];

        for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            if (box[k].min.x <= box[i].max.x &&
                box[k].min.y <= box[i].max.y &&
                box[k].min.z <= box[i].max.z &&
                box[k].max.x >= box[i].min.x &&
                box[k].max.y >= box[i].max.y &&
                box[k].max.z >= box[i].max.z) {

                /* A collision is possible, since the axis-aligned
                   bounding boxes intersect. Check. */

                const vec3d p = { prev[i].x - prev[k].x,
                                  prev[i].y - prev[k].y,
                                  prev[i].z - prev[k].z };
                const vec3d d = { p.x - curr[i].x + curr[k].x,
                                  p.y - curr[i].y + curr[k].y,
                                  p.z - curr[i].z + curr[k].z };
                const double tn = p.x * d.x + p.y * d.y + p.z * d.z;
                const double td = d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y + d.z * d.z;
                if (tn >= 0.0 && tn <= td) {
                    const double  t1 = tn / td;
                    const double  t0 = 1.0 - t1;
                    const vec3d   loc_k = { t0*prev[k].x + t1*curr[k].x,
                                            t0*prev[k].y + t1*curr[k].y,
                                            t0*prev[k].z + t1*curr[k].z };
                    const vec3d   loc_i = { t0*prev[i].x + t1*curr[i].x,
                                            t0*prev[i].y + t1*curr[i].y,
                                            t0*prev[i].z + t1*curr[i].z };
                    const vec3d   delta = { loc_i.x - loc_k.x,
                                            loc_i.y - loc_k.y,
                                            loc_i.z - loc_k.z };
                    if (delta.x*delta.x + delta.y*delta.y + delta.z*delta.z <=
                        (radius[i] + radius[k])*(radius[i] + radius[k])) {

                        /* Collision occurs at time t  (0 <= t && t <= 1),
                           between object k (at loc_k) and object i (at loc_i).
                        */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, more than two objects can collide during the same time step, although that is exceedingly rare. Thing is, if you "remove" any of the colliding objects from consideration during the above loop, you might miss them. (I suspect it is rare enough to not worry about, but I am a paranoid mind, and don't like not worrying about things. :)

To avoid that, I would just save the collisions in the above loop into some kind of an array, or a [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Then, after the above code, merge any colliding objects. (Note that the disjoint-set data structure makes this easier, because if you have collisions A-B, B-C, and C-D, the disjoint set actually resolves that to A-B, A-C, and A-D. Otherwise, if you join B to A, and destroy B, joining C to B is impossible. Again, this is a corner case, but not worrying about such corner cases is the difference between having a reliable simulator, and a simulator that crashes one every thousand simulations, or perhaps one in a billion timesteps, for an unseen ununderstood reason.)

Comment: thanks for the advice! I'm not sure I fully understand your solution but it works perfectly.
Why exactly would the spheres be "pills" or cylinders with hemispherical caps? I am using "gluSphere" to render the planets, I was under the impression this constructed a sphere purely out of primitives (triangles?).

Comment: @offwavesurfer: Only in the sense when you consider the axis-aligned bounding box. Now that you point it out, I could have restated it as the axis-aligned bounding box that contains the spherical object at both the end of the time step, and start of the time step. (If you connect them with a cylinder of the same radius, representing the path the object takes *during* the time step, you get the pill shape.) Let me see if I can restate it better; me fail English often, you see.

Comment: @offwavesurfer: Let me know if the new explanations are easier to grasp.  If not, I can always iterate as many times as needed to make it better. :)  You see, I find it important that people have reliable information on how to write better simulators, including collision detection between spherical objects, and how to do it efficiently.  I am not helping just you, here; I am trying to help everyone that is looking at simulations and thinking of how to do collision detection effectively, and happen to stumble upon this question and answer via a web search.

Comment: That's very interesting. I hadn't considered that the bounding box would contain the sphere's current AND previous position, but having read you're edited answer that makes a lot more sense, what with representing 3D space and time in a simulation. I had actually incorporated your method of collision detection, albeit incorrectly. It now works perfectly and the simulation seems a bit smoother too! Thanks very much for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have a discrete time simulation, with a fixed time step.

Your collision detection doesn't seem sufficient. If speeds of the planets are high enough, and their radii are small enough, you may have them just passing through each other, without collision being ever detected. The situation gets even worse if the collision is not a head on, but rather tangential.

A more prudent approach is to watch not the planets, but the balls of a larger radius (dynamically dependent on the planet's speed), and when two *balls* collide, switch to a finer time step.

If you go this way, separate simulation from visualization carefully.

Comment: Also, you can treat the movement of each object during the current time step as a line segment, and check if the line segments "intersect" (rather, if the right circular cylinders with axes represented by the line segments intersect). You can then do an intermediate time step at the collision moment. Look at the [Skew lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines#Distance) wikipedia article. In a computer program, it is much faster to calculate the *squared* distance (as square root is relatively slow); when `a` and `b` are nonnegative, `sqrt(a) < sqrt(b)` only if `a < b`.

Comment: Thanks for fhe advice! I actually have a fairly basic dynamic time step, just measuring the time to render the previous frame and comparing it to the time to render the 'current' frame using time.h